# Use external Portfile for local MacPorts

Tags: python, macports

I'm quite happy with MacPorts, but every so often I run across something that doesn't have a Portfile.  For example, I'd like to play around with Python and the PDF generator libharu ([link](http://libharu.org/)).  It seems that there is a Portfile available for libharu [here](https://github.com/sakuro/macports/blob/master/print/libharu/Portfile).

Is there a way to set up MacPorts such that, with every `port selfupdate` this Portfile is updated from the remote github.com location as well?  I do *not* want to have to maintain this locally all the time.

(The next step then is dealing with pyharu for which I couldn't find a Portfile yet, but there's hopefully enough documentation [here](https://github.com/libharu/libharu/blob/master/if/python/README.python) or [here](http://libfir.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/aliens/libharu-2.1.0/if/python/README.python))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository you linked is a clone of the official MacPorts port tree. As a consequence, any file in this github repository is also in the standard port tree. `port info libharu` should thus work out of the box on your system.

To also answer the now obsolete part of your question about syncing a ports tree from git: Yes, MacPorts trunk supports syncing port trees from git (see [this part of the relevant source](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/base/src/macports1.0/macports.tcl?marks=2229-2253#L2229)). This is not available in a released version, though, and will make its way into MacPorts 2.2.

To use this feature, create a standard clone in a location of your choice, ensure the user macports has read and write access to this location, edit your `/opt/local/etc/macports/sources.conf` and append `file:///path/to/your/clone`.

Comment: Hah!  Thanks, yes, it's in the port tree.  It took two days for a selfupdate (ImageMagick +graphviz is broken) and some fiddling around, but now everything is up-to-date and libharu is there.  Unfortunately, the Python bindings (pyharu) aren't.